# jetpack compose ошибка сборки Symbol for kotlin.collections/mutableMapOf|-4813910536206556932[0] is unbound

Tags: kotlin, build-error, android-jetpack-compose

при сборке проекта, я получаю следующую ошибку

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Symbol for kotlin.collections/mutableMapOf|-4813910536206556932[0] is unbound
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrBindablePublicSymbolBase.getOwner(IrPublicSymbolBase.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrSimpleFunctionPublicSymbolImpl.getOwner(IrPublicSymbolBase.kt:74)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitCall(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:663)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:199)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.transformChildren(IrBody.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.accept(IrBody.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.transform(IrBody.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrField.transformChildren(IrField.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrField.accept(IrField.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.transformChildren(IrClass.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:66)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitClass$s780614737(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitClass$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:466)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitClass$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:465)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor$siblings$1.invoke(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.siblings(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:194)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitClass(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:465)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.transformChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitPackageFragment(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:47)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitFile$s780614737(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitFile$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:549)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitFile$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:479)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.root(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:152)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitFile(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:479)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.accept(IrFileImpl.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFile.transform(IrFile.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrModuleFragmentImpl.transformChildren(IrModuleFragmentImpl.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.lower(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:171)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$lambda-1(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:146)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$default(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:331)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:170)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:434)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:357)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:299)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:622)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1713)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

mutableMapOf нигде в коде не используется. Из ряда Mutable в коде есть только MutableLiveData и MutableStateFlow в ViewModel

вот build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0-alpha02'
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

и build.gradle:app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dev.prokrostinatorbl.raspisanie"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 48
        versionName "4.1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
            useIR = true
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    "-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies",
                    "-P",
                    "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
            ]
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        viewBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
    }
}

dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'

 //Jetpack
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version")
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version")
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version")
    // Material Design
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version")
    // Material design icons
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$compose_version")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version")
    // Integration with observables
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:$compose_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0-alpha01")

    implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:$compose_version"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    // UI Tests
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version")
}
```

Comment: А вот как у вас с  compose_version = '1.2.0-alpha02' получается использовать такую старую версию ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20'?

Comment: поставил kotlin_version = '1.6.0', ошибка сохранилась

Comment: Ну так то гугл говорит, что нужно удалить `kotlin-android-extensions`

Comment: теперь работает, спасибо!

Comment: Оформил ответ чтобы другие не искали. Кстати, последняя версия котлина 1.6.10

Answer (score 2):

Английский so [говорит](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70425607/kotlin-1-6-jetpack-compose-1-1-0-compilation-error), что нужно удалить плагин `kotlin-android-extensions`